# GIT Batch delete entire project with certain file names

Tags: bash, git

A previous developer was using Dreamweaver and the whole site is riddled with _notes/dwsync.xml.

Is there any way to do a batch git rm and remove any file with the name dwsync.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -name dwsync.xml -exec git rm {} \+
```